# Jira REST API - CURL command succeeds, swift program fails

Tags: swift, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to use the Jira REST API to update issues programmatically via a MacOS program, written in Swift. I have a Jira API Token and have succeeded using CURL. Here is the command:

```
curl --request PUT \
  --url 'https://xxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/SAN-2' \
  --user 'xxx@yyy.com:zzz' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
"update": {
"timetracking": [
{
"edit": {
"originalEstimate": "1w 1d"
}
}
]
}
}'
```

Where zzz is the API Token. This works and the field is updated correctly.

The Swift version mirrors this as closely as I can, but fails with the error

**Response: {"errorMessages":["Issue does not exist or you do not have permission to see it."],"errors":{}}**

Here is the Swift code:

```
        let tokenString = "xxx@yyy.com:zzz"

        guard let encodedTokenString = tokenString.data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedData() else { fatalError("Can't encode token") }

        let authString = String("Token token=\(encodedTokenString)")

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://xxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/SAN-2")

        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't create a static URL")
        }

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)

        request.addValue(authString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        request.httpMethod = "PUT"

        let dataString = "{\"update\": {\"timetracking\": [{\"edit\": {\"originalEstimate\": \"1w 1d\"}}]}}".utf8

        let body = Data(dataString)    

        request.httpBody = body

        let session = URLSession.shared

        session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            guard let data = data, let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as String?, !responseString.isEmpty else {
                print("No valid response!")
                return
            }
            print("Response: " + responseString)

        }.resume()
```

I clearly have permission to edit the issue and it exists. I have an API token, and it works. What am I missing?

Comment: I believe it should be `let authString = String("Bearer \(encodedTokenString)")` The Authorization header should have a format `Authorization: type credentials`, and I have not heard of Authorization type `Token`. Usually with token the type is `Bearer`

Comment: Thanks Kiril. I tried changing "Token" to "Bearer" with the same results. Were there other changes you suggested? I'm not sure what "The Authorization header should have a format Authorization: type credentials" is implying, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two issues:

**1) You're setting the encodedTokenString to be Data instead of a string.**

```
guard let encodedTokenString = tokenString.data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedData() else { fatalError("Can't encode token") }
```

change the above to:

```
guard let encodedTokenString = tokenString.data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedString() else { fatalError("Can't encode token") }
```

**2) Your authString should be:**

```
`let authString = String("Basic \(encodedTokenString)")`
```